# Display video in an existing block

Tags: blocks, files

Thank you in advance for reading my question.

Seems like many people have asked a similar question to what I'm about to ask, but mine has a subtle difference that I can't resolve.

I need to the ability to play a self-hosted video in a block on my Drupal 7 site. Per many people's recommendation, I downloaded/installed the Video module. That would work - if it was the only thing I'm displaying in the block. But there will be HTML content above and below the video, something I can't seem to produce with the Video module.

My preference is to self-host the video, not put it on YouTube or anything like that.

I hope my scenario/question makes sense. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: will this HTML be generic or specific to each video?

Comment: There will only be a single video.. so I could hard-code a path to a file, if that's what you're getting at. I suppose the video could change, but I'd just change it manually.

Comment: If it's just one video in one block, you could copy `block.tpl.php` out of `modules/block` and into your theme and named appropriately (see https://drupal.org/node/1089656 for name suggestions) and put that html in there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, honestly, I'm not following at all. I already have a block with the HTML content, I just want to add a video to the middle of it. Seems like it shouldn't be such a complicated process...

Comment: Ah.  I thought it was the other way around, that you had a block that just had a video in it and you wanted to wrap it with additional HTML.  Check out the Media Module (https://drupal.org/project/media) as that might do more of what you want.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. My big problem with the Media Module is that it insists on using a Flash-based player for the video. I'm trying to avoid Flash like the plague.

Comment: And I was able to work around the Flash issue as well. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction! (I would up vote you, but I don't have enough reputation yet.)